# Where to add request.meta on my script to crawl once

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I downloaded [scrapy-crawl-once](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/scrapy-crawl-once) and I am trying to run it in my program. I want to scrape each book's url from the first page of  http://books.toscrape.com/ and then scrape the title of the book from that url. I know I can scrape each book title from the first page, but as practice for scrapy-crawl-once, I wanted to do it this way. I already added the middlewares and need to know where to add request.meta. From doing some research, there isn't much codes out there for some example guidance so was hoping someone can help here. I learned the basics of python two weeks ago so struggling right now. I tried this, but the results hasn't changed. Can someone help me out please. I added [:2] so that if I change it to [:3], I can show myself that it works.

```
def parse(self, response):
    all_the_books = response.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']")
    for div in all_the_books[:2]:
        book_link = 'http://books.toscrape.com/' + div.xpath(".//h3/a/@href").get()
        request = scrapy.Request(book_link, self.parse_book)
        request.meta['book_link'] = book_link
        yield request

def parse_book(self, response):
    name = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6 product_main']/h1/text()").get()
    yield {
        'name': name,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its docs says

> To avoid crawling a particular page multiple times set
>   request.meta['crawl_once'] = True

so you need to do

```
def parse(self, response):
    all_the_books = response.xpath("//article[@class='product_pod']")
    for div in all_the_books[:2]:
        book_link = 'http://books.toscrape.com/' + div.xpath(".//h3/a/@href").get()
        request = scrapy.Request(book_link, self.parse_book)
        request.meta['crawl_once'] = True
        yield request
```

And it will not crawl that link again

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Would you happen to know if I implemented it right? I wasn't sure whether to make scrapy.Request = request. I just saw someone doing it so I thought it would be right, but maybe I am implementing the whole thing wrong.